# Rename column names by pattern

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, rename

I want to rename my columns cause it's too long, for example:

`chrX:99883666-99894988_TSPAN6_ENSG00000000003.10` to `TSPAN6`

`chrX:99839798-99854882_TNMD_ENSG00000000005.5` to `TNMD`

`chr20:49505584-49575092_DPM1_ENSG00000000419.8` to `DPM1`

How can I rename it consider the elements I want to delete differs from every columns?

Answer (score 1):

Using `strsplit` we can try:

```
names(df) <- strsplit(names(df), "_")[[1]][2]
```

If you only want to target a certain subset of names, then simply filter `names(df)` using that logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using regex. How about extracting a word between two underscores ?

```
x <- c("chrX:99883666-99894988_TSPAN6_ENSG00000000003.10", 
       "chrX:99839798-99854882_TNMD_ENSG00000000005.5", 
       "chr20:49505584-49575092_DPM1_ENSG00000000419.8")

sub('.*?_(\\w+)_.*', '\\1', x)
#[1] "TSPAN6" "TNMD"   "DPM1"
```

For names of the column you can use `names(df)` instead of `x`.

```
names(df) <- sub('.*?_(\\w+)_.*', '\\1', names(df))
```

and if you prefer `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% rename_with(~sub('.*?_(\\w+)_.*', '\\1', .))
```